# Number of logical reads explodes with one extra inner join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-performance, query-performance, sqlperformance

I have two tables that looks almost identical. When I select from either of them my logical reads are around 8.000-10.000 reads. But when I inner join them, I get around 380.000 logical reads.

I use MS SQL 2012.

**The query I have problem with looks like this:**

```
SELECT ac.ID AS AccountID
    ,ab.Balance
    ,abc.BalanceInAccountCurrency
FROM dbo.Dates d
INNER JOIN dbo.Accounts ac ON d.[Date] BETWEEN ac.CreationDate AND ac.ClosureDate
INNER JOIN dbo.AccountBalances ab ON ab.AccountID  = ac.ID AND d.[Date] BETWEEN ab.CreationDate  AND ab.ClosureDate
INNER JOIN dbo.AccountBalancesInAccountCurrency abc ON abc.AccountID = ac.ID AND d.[Date] BETWEEN abc.CreationDate AND abc.ClosureDate
WHERE d.[Date] = DATEFROMPARTS(2017,06,20);
```

[image]

**When I only join with AccountBalances like this:**

```
SELECT ac.ID AS AccountID
      ,ab.Balance
FROM dbo.Dates d
INNER JOIN dbo.Accounts ac ON d.[Date] BETWEEN ac.CreationDate AND ac.ClosureDate
INNER JOIN dbo.AccountBalances ab ON ab.AccountID  = ac.ID AND d.[Date] BETWEEN ab.CreationDate  AND ab.ClosureDate
WHERE d.[Date] = DATEFROMPARTS(2017,06,20);
```

[image]

And I get similar results when I only join with AccountBalancesInAccountCurrency.

My primary key/clustered index looks like this on both tables:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AccountBalances] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_AccountBalances] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    ClosureDate DESC,
    CreationDate DESC,
    AccountID ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Execution Plans**

[Both Tables](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1E0fdbff)
[image]

[AccountBalancesInAccountCurrency Only](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJyMN_bMG)
[image]

[AccountBalances Only](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyQVX_Zff)
[image]

**Extra info**

The query results in 170460 rows and total logical reads is 376.000.
But if I uses "top 170000" in my query the total logical reads is only 44.000. Statistics IO looks like this:
[image]

[And the execution plan looks like this](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1qQQnbfM)
[image]

Comment: Can you post both execution plans? Use http://pastetheplan.com/

Comment: @alroc is right, we would need the plans to check but looks like you are missing indexes on the date columns.

Comment: yes, I will post them later. The tables are in danish and I need to translate them :)

Comment: Hi again. I have attached the execution plans now.

Comment: When you have query tables it does an index scan instead of an index seek on the AccountBalances table causing it to read 23521382 rows instead of 170460 rows. When is the last time stats were updated on these tables?

Comment: Hi @ChrisAlbert. Yes, I have done sp_updatestats and ALTER INDEX ALL ON dbo.Accounts REBUILD on all tables, but nothing helps.

Comment: What does the join in the middle accomplish?

Comment: Hi @theMayer. AccountBalances and AccountBalancesInAccountCurrency are almost identical tables but AccountBalances the balance is in the bank's accounting currency and AccountBalancesInAccountCurrency the balance is in the account currency. In my example AccountBalances are always in DKK and AccountBalancesInAccountCurrency balance can be any currency eg. EUR, USD etc.

Comment: Isn't this the same information with different presentation? I would set up a scalar function do do the translation, thus eliminating the join and the associated operations. It's clear that is where the bottleneck is.

Comment: what if you try adding the `WITH (FORCESEEK)` hint to both of the account balances tables?

Comment: Hi @theMayer. Yes, it´s the same information, but I can´t  make a scalar function because I haven´t got the exchange rate.

Comment: Hi @MartinSmith. I have just tried it, didn't work :( I stopped it when the request passed 7 min. Usually it takes 30 seconds, when I join both tables.

Comment: I think your best bet is post the full structure that repeats the problem for you, e.g. the script for tables, indexes. Also that often helps you narrow things down, try recreating from scratch just those couple tables (and using some like that script to bootstrap) in a new db, add some test data if needed to add more rows. And something like that could make it easier for devs here to test, compare, and give you better ideas.

Comment: How is the plan for this? `SELECT ac.ID AS AccountID
    ,ab.Balance
    ,abc.BalanceInAccountCurrency
FROM  dbo.Accounts ac  
INNER JOIN dbo.AccountBalances ab ON ab.AccountID  = ac.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.AccountBalancesInAccountCurrency abc ON abc.AccountID = ac.ID 
WHERE '2017-06-20' BETWEEN ac.CreationDate AND ac.ClosureDate
AND '2017-06-20' BETWEEN  ab.CreationDate  AND ab.ClosureDate
AND '2017-06-20'  BETWEEN abc.CreationDate AND abc.ClosureDate`

Comment: Hi @MartinSmith. Much better. Logical is 21.000 and the exection plan look like this: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1-Y4nXzf. But I still want to make the other thing work, because I´am trying to make a view that orther (Sales and economy people) in the organisation can use.

Comment: Hi @NSGaga. I've also thought about that. Just give me a little time to make the script.

Comment: instead of a view you can make a parameterised inline table valued function that accepts a date parameter.

Comment: Hi @MartinSmith. Mmm, I can try that, but I would like a view to work and I can´t see why it should not work. A view is also more suited for my current project.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem.

**1.** 
AccountBalances contains balances in the bank's accounting currency which is DKK and AccountBalancesInAccountCurrency contains balances in the account currency and also in DKK. The majority of the currencies are DKK and exists in both tables. I therefore removed all DKK balances from AccountBalancesInAccountCurrency and made a left join to that table.

**2.**
I also changed the primary key on AccountBalancesInAccountCurrency from:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AccountBalances] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_AccountBalances] 
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    ClosureDate DESC,
    CreationDate DESC,
    AccountID ASC
)
```

to:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AccountBalancesInAccountCurrency] ADD  CONSTRAINT 
[PK_AccountBalancesInAccountCurrency] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AccountID] ASC,
    [ClosureDate] DESC
)
```

Now my IO look like this:
[image]

[and my execution plan like this](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1MrPIFzz).

Thanks for all the comments that led me on my way.

Happy holidays!